# Javascript - using before defined

Tags: javascript

Recently I asked a question regarding my triangle calculations Coded in JavaScript. Basically I went to JSLint (*A JavaScript debug facility*) to acquire some data as to why nothing inside the function and procedure is working where as it all looks good and I followed previously given advice, but I believe this is a separate issue. I have posted the code below:

```
    <html>
<head>
<link href="stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

/*  Key/Legend
Var
    inp1 = input1
    inp2 = input2
    inp3 = input3
    Triangle_Inputs = Form Name

    */

/* Notes

    In computing, a parser is one of the components in an interpreter or 
    compiler that checks for correct syntax and builds a data structure 
    (often some kind of parse tree, abstract syntax tree or other hierarchical structure) 
    implicit in the input tokens.


    Technique
    if (side1 is equal to side2 AND side 2 is equal to side3) {equalitateral}

    if (side1 is equal to side2 AND side 2 doesn't equal to side3) {isosceles}

    if (side1 doesn't equal to side2 AND side2 doesn't equal to side 3 AND side 3 doesn't equal side 1) {scalene}

    http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

    */


function checkinputs(){
/* Var = parseInt(document.Name_Of_Element_Form.Field_Name(Input).value); */
/* Input Fields */
inp1 = parseInt(document.Triangle_Inputs.input1.value);
inp2 = parseInt(document.Triangle_Inputs.input2.value);
inp3 = parseInt(document.Triangle_Inputs.input3.value);
/* Side options */
sideA = (inp1);
sideB = (inp2);
sideC = (inp3);
    if (sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC) {
    alert("Equalateral");
    }
    if (sideA == sideB && != sideC) {
    alert("Isosceles");
    }
    if (sideA != sideB == sideC) {
    alert("Isosceles");
    }
    if (sideA != sideB != sideC != sideA) {
    alert("Scalene!");
    }
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="Container">

<div id="Header"><h1></h1></div>

        <div id="Content_1">
                <div id="Explanation">
                This calculator will determine what
                triangle you have made depending on
                the integer values in the input fields.

                </div>
                <div id="Form">
                    <FORM NAME="Triangle_Inputs" METHOD="GET">
                    Enter the triangle values below: <br>
                    <p>
                    <h4>Side 1: </h4><BR>
                    <INPUT TYPE="Integer" NAME="input1" VALUE=""><P>
                    <h4>Side 2: </h4><BR>
                    <INPUT TYPE="Integer" NAME="input2" VALUE=""><P>
                    <h4>Side 3:</h4> <BR>
                    <INPUT TYPE="Integer" NAME="input3"  VALUE=""><P>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Submit" Value="Submit" Class="Submit" onClick="checkinputs()">
                    </FORM>
                </div>
                <div id="Verbal_Output">
                    <h2>You made a:</h2>
                    <p>        
                    <h2>Triangle</h2>
                </div>

            </div>
            <p>
            <p>
        <div id="Content_2">

        <div id="Image_Output">asdad</div>
    </div>      
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

This is the site itself, Ignoring the div tags. I want to know why I can't click the button and more the the point why JSlint says:

> inp1 = parseInt(document.Triangle_Inputs.input1.value);
>
> line 39 character 1 'inp1' was used before it was defined.

for the inp1,inp2 and inp3.

edit:

My understanding of using Variables was incorrect, I was listing them without using ","s.
Instead I was calling one variable and the rest I wasn't.

Comment: You're missing `var` that's why

Comment: Hello, would you care to elaborate, would it be 

Var inp1 = integer;
Var inp2 = integer;
Var inp3 = integer;

thank you :)

Comment: Yes, when you define a variable, put `var ` before it (in lowercase).

Comment: Thank you Abraham, this will be noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var checkinputs = function() {
/* Input Fields */
var sideA = parseInt(document.Triangle_Inputs.input1.value),
    sideB = parseInt(document.Triangle_Inputs.input2.value),
    sideC = parseInt(document.Triangle_Inputs.input3.value);

alert (sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC) ? 'Equilateral' :
      (sideA == sideB && sideA != sideC) ? 'Isosceles' :
      (sideA != sideB && sideA == sideC) ? 'Isosceles' :
      (sideA != sideB && sideA != sideC && sideB != sideC) ? 'Scalene' :
      'logic needs improvement';
}
```

I noticed also that your logic is a little bit flawed, so I've edited it to what I think looks right.

Comment: @OP notice the `,` which means you're declaring 3 vars using the var keyword once.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response. I just tried this and I'm still having problems. There is no popup.

Should I upload it to my webspace?

Comment: Your logic is totally wrong. I'm fixing it; give me two minutes.

Comment: Thanks Jezen, Hopefully I can compare and contrast :)

Comment: I'm really no good at maths, so my answer can be improved upon. Basically, if you see the alert 'logic needs improvement', then it means the testing logic isn't robust enough.

Comment: Reviewing your code, there are many other issues that need solving, that are outside the scope of my answer. You need an event handler, *i.e.*, a point in time when the `checkinputs()` function should be called. The scripts also needs to know what `Triangle_Inputs` is.